# Default values in tableselect

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom module that, among other things, shows the user of a certain role. I want some of the users in this tableselect, do already be checked and I have and arry with these uids.

Now, how do I chedk default values in my list? See code below:

```
$companies = 'mail1@test.org,test2@test.org';
$uids = array();
$comp_mail = explode(',', $companies);
foreach ($comp_mail as $mail) {
    $uids[] = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE mail = '$mail'")->fetchField();
}

$form['msg']['accounts'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => in_array($uids),
    '#empty' => 'no companies',
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Clive, this is how it now looks, and works:

```
    $uids = array();
    $comp_mail = explode(',', $companies);
    foreach ($comp_mail as $mail) {
        $uid = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE mail = '$mail'")->fetchField();
        $uids[$uid] = TRUE;
    }

//      drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($uids, TRUE)); // Debug

    $form['msg']['accounts'] = array(
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#default_value' => $uids,
        '#empty' => 'No companies',
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

`in_array()` returns a boolean (and takes two arguments), whereas Drupal is expecting an array to be passed for the default value.

The default value array needs to be keyed by the same key used for the options array, so in this case `uid`. The value for each array element should be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, to mark the element as checked or unchecked respectively.

```
$uids[1] = TRUE;
$uids[2] = FALSE;
$uids[3] = TRUE;
// etc.

$form['msg']['accounts'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => $uids,
  '#empty' => 'no companies',
);
```

**EDIT**

I haven't tested the following, but since your `$uids` array contains only the array keys you want checked, and a positive number is automatically cast to a boolean `TRUE` in PHP, you might get away converting your array in one step:

```
$uids = drupal_map_assoc($uids);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I changed it as above, but no companies are checked.

Comment: You need to make sure your `$options` array is keyed by user id...then it'll work :)

Comment: Array with the nids I want checked ($nids):
Array
(
    [0] => 1635
    [1] => 1499
)

Array of the list ($options):
Array
(
    [1160] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test1
            [mail] => test1@test.org
        )

    [1493] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test2
            [mail] => mail2$test.org
        )
)

Comment: If your `$options` array contains node ids then your default value array must also contain node ids...otherwise how will Drupal match them up?!

Comment: $options array is the account id (uid).
Here's (almost) the complete code:
http://pastebin.com/n50m5EBY

Comment: @DanielHolm My bad it's slightly different than what I said, I've updated the answer. Also have a look at [this comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_tableselect/7#comment-19184) on the `theme_tableselect` docs page, it has the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Option and default array need to have the same keys; change `$uids[] =` to `$uids['same_key_as_in_option_array'] =` and remove `in_array()`.

I also use 0 for `FALSE`, and 1 for `TRUE`, but I am not sure if this needs to be like this.

For '#empty', I would use a `t()`'d value.

Answer (score -1):

In looking at the code, the form api expects the default to be set with '#value', not '#default_value'.  I hope this helps someone else avoid the frustration I have experienced!

form.inc: line 3458

```
  if ($element['#multiple']) {
    $value = is_array($element['#value']) ? $element['#value'] : array();
  }
```

form.inc: line 3486

```
  $element[$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $title,
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#return_value' => $key,
    '#default_value' => isset($value[$key]) ? $key : NULL,
    '#attributes' => $element['#attributes'],
  );
```

Comment: I'm discovering the same thing.  If I use default_value, nothing is selected.  If I use value, everything is selected that I want, but any changes made on the form are not passed to the submit.